# Does Jooq support Joda-Time?

Tags: java, sql, jodatime, jooq

We are looking for date time support for different timezones.
It seems Hibernate supports Joda time, any idea does JOOQ supports the same?

Comment: You have to write `customType` and `forcedTypes` if you want JodaTime types code generated. This means you'll probably want to standardize on a column naming convention, which is a benefit in the end. To avoid timezone issues, in my case I wrote only `Instant`, `LocalDate`, and `LocalDateTime` converters.

Comment: @BenManes: Would be interesting to read a blog post / case study about that experience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) by itself does not support Joda-Time, nor any other third-party data type. But you can easily configure the jOOQ code generator to rewrite data types through custom converters. This is documented here:

- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/data-type-conversion/
- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-types/