# jOOQ: Allowed-Character constraints?

Tags: java, jooq

I am considering moving from Hibernate to jOOQ but I can't find e.g.
how to have Pattern-Constraints on a `String` like this in Hibernate:

```
@NotEmpty(message = "Firstname cannot be empty")
@Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$", message = "First Name can only contain characters.")
private String firstname;
```

How would I do that in jOOQ?

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding what JOOQ is about. JOOQ is *not* about validating Beans wrt. JSR-303 (bean-validation) standards. It's simply not intended to do that for you... Hibernate does that. but it's not mandatory for O/R-Mappers

Comment: @Vogel612 Oh alright, I didn't know that. I was taking it for granted because Hibernate does that for me using annotations on its entities. I am not very experienced with libraries for designing databases. Do you know how I would implement such checks? Is it common practice to implement this in the DAO Layer then or am I completely mistaken here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The "jOOQ way"

The "jOOQ way" to do such validation would be to create either:

- A `CHECK` constraint in the database.
- A trigger in the database.
- A domain in the database.

After all, if you want to ensure data integrity, the database is where such constraints and integrity checks belong (possibly in addition to functionally equivalent client-side validation). Imagine a batch job, a Perl script, or even a JDBC statement that bypasses JSR-303 validation. You'll find yourself with corrupt data in no time.

If you do want to implement client-side validation, you can still use JSR-303 on your DTOs, which interact with your UI, for instance. But you will have to perform validation *before* passing the data to jOOQ for storage ([as artbristol explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32693381/521799)).

#### Using a `Converter`

You could, however, use your own custom type by declaring a `Converter` on individual columns and by [registering such `Converter` with the source code generator](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-types/).

Essentially, a `Converter` is:

```
public interface Converter<T, U> extends Serializable {
    U from(T databaseObject);
    T to(U userObject);
    Class<T> fromType();
    Class<U> toType();
}
```

In your case, you could implement your annotations as such:

```
public class NotEmptyAlphaNumericValidator implements Converter<String, String> {

    // Validation
    public String to(String userObject) {
        assertNotEmpty(userObject);
        assertMatches(userObject, "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$");
        return userObject;
    }

    // Boilerplate
    public String from(String databaseObject) { return databaseObject; }
    public Class<String> fromType() { return String.class; }
    public Class<String> toType() { return String.class; }
}
```

Note that this is more of a workaround, as `Converter` hasn't been designed for this use-case, even if it can perfectly implement it.

#### Using formal client-side validation

There's also a pending feature request [#4543](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4543) to add more support for client-side validation. As of jOOQ 3.7, this is not yet implemented.

Comment: Hi! So, basically I could use a validator or a converter but what I should do is use the [pattern matching]8http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) of PostgreSQL e.g. `LIKE`. Thank you for the `Converter` example but I am pretty sure that I really should go for the database-level validation! I would use such a `Converter` to use joda-time though! :)

Comment: Yes, pattern matching in a `CHECK` constraint sounds like the way to go. And yes, JodaTime support is the perfect use-case for `Converters`

Comment: Alright! Thank you for your elaborated answer! It helps me a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you don't try to use jOOQ in a 'hibernate/JPA' way. Leave the jOOQ generated classes as they are and map to your own domain classes manually, which you are free to annotate however you like. You can then call a JSR validator before you attempt to persist them.

For example, jOOQ might generate the following class

```
public class BookRecord extends UpdatableRecordImpl<BookRecord> {

    private String firstname;

    public void setId(Integer value) { /* ... */ }

    public Integer getId() { /* ... */ }

}
```

You can create your own domain object

```
public class Book {

    @NotEmpty(message = "Firstname cannot be empty")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$", message = "First Name can only contain characters.")
    private String firstname;

    public void setId(Integer value) { /* ... */ }

    public Integer getId() { /* ... */ }

}
```

and map by hand once you've retrieved a `BookRecord`, in your DAO layer

```
Book book = new Book();
book.setId(bookRecord.getId());
book.setFirstname(bookRecord.getFirstname());
```

This seems quite tedious (and ORM tries to spare you this tedium) but actually it scales quite well to complicated domain objects, in my opinion, and it's always easy to figure out the flow of data in your application.

Comment: Hi! Sorry I am not sure if I get this right. Does this mean I should create my database, reverse engineer / generated jOOQ files and then wrap those over some higher level class wrapper? Sorry if that's a stupid question :D

Comment: Stefan - yes, that's exactly what I mean. Not necessarily a wrapper, I would have different classes. Just from experience, it's a little more work, but you avoid all the hibernate-style nastiness of trying to munge your domain into some unsuitable classes (the fundamental ORM problem)

Comment: Okay I see - thank you for that info. It's so hard to imagine such things without the actual practical experience. Is there a chance that you know a project e.g. on github that follows your approach so I can take a look at its code? Or maybe you have a veeery small example of this approach that you can add to your answer? I have accepted Lukas' answer already but I wouldn't mind creating a new one that aims specifically on this "wrapping" issue. :)

Comment: For the record, it might be worth mentioning that there is a `bookRecord.into(Class)` method (and an inverse `bookRecord.from(value)` method) that maps values per naming convention...

Comment: @LukasEder, yes, that's useful if you don't mind reflection (I prefer 'find usages' and things to continue to work, so I prefer to map manually)